# Curl IMAP search on both subject and body

Tags: curl, command-line-interface, imap

I'm using Curl windows binary on cli to do some IMAP searches.
i want to search on both subject and body, but at the moment i can't find the right syntax, so I'm doing it in 2 different commands like this:

curl imap://mike:1234@localhost/INBOX?SUBJECT%20TEST

curl imap://mike:1234@localhost/INBOX?BODY%20TEST

i see that the IMAP specification has an OR:

OR

i tried something like this, but didn't work:

curl imap://mike:1234@localhost/INBOX?OR (SUBJECT TEST) (BODY TEST) // WITHOUT PERCENT ENCODING

curl imap://mike:1234@localhost/INBOX?OR%20(SUBJECT%20TEST)%20(BODY%20TEST) // WITH PERCENT ENCODING

as a workaround i found that i can use the TEXT command, which searches on the header (including the subject) and body, the problem is that it can bring some false positive if one of the words is part of another header.
using:

curl imap://mike:1234@localhost/INBOX?TEXT%20TEST

any idea if it's possible to search only on subject and body in the same command?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks correct. Maybe your IMAP server doesn't handle the BODY keyword the way we would expect. Many servers optimize their search index in a way that makes this incomplete. To test the OR syntax, try `OR (SUBJECT TEST_A) (SUBJECT TEST_B)`. To test if BODY keyword works as expected, try `BODY TEST` on its own. These tests will help you to narrow down the problem.